Реализовать логику работы сайта через Vue Cli
Я новичок в этом деле, хотел спросить как реализовать некую логику работы сайта через Vue Cli. Есть такой сайт "сытая морда" https://morda72.ru/ - интернет магазин. Когда на headere нажимаешь на ссылку "Кошки", то открывается страница с категориями, когда нажимаешь на одну из них к примеру "корм для кошек", открывается список товаров и левый столбец с фильтрами именно под эту категорию, если нажать на другую категорию к примеру "Витамины", то в левом столбце будут уже другие фильтры. У меня вопрос именно про левый столбец, вот как именно мне реализовать это? Т.е. мне создать отдельную страницу под каждую такую категорию, где будет свой столбец с фильтрами? Или
отдельный компонент где к примеру остальные фильтры будут скрываться, которые не относятся к этой категории товаров?

Фильтры должны исходить из товаров содержащихся в категории, это уже вам должен предоставить API сервис, в wordpress уже есть готовые решения для данной задачи. Какой у вас стек технологий? Как вы получаете данные, на чём у вас бэкенд?

@MoloF Я бэкенд не знаю, я сейчас изучаю фронтенд и верстаю на данный момент макет, который видимо взяли из этого сайта. С wordpress тоже не знаком.
